# File download from Google API v3 in PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Have been looking all over for downloading a file from google drive with the API as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads). In the flow, was able to pass the authentication of the user, and was able to list the files with the below code.

```
 echo "<br>" . count($results->getFiles()). " File(s) found" ; 
        echo "<hr>";
        foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
            echo "File Name is " . $file->getName() . " And file ID is ". $file->getId() . " Type is ".$file->getMimeType() ."<br><pre>";
            print_r($file);
            echo "</pre><hr>";
        }
```

And the output is something like

```
100 File(s) found
File Name is invoice receipt.pdf And file ID is 0B5CWXJTNwALMOEJkdzFvMVVsVFE Type is application/pdf
Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => spaces
    [appProperties] => 
    [capabilitiesType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities
    [capabilitiesDataType:protected] => 
    [contentHintsType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints
    [contentHintsDataType:protected] => 
    [createdTime] => 
    [description] => 
    [explicitlyTrashed] => 
    [fileExtension] => 
    [folderColorRgb] => 
    [fullFileExtension] => 
    [headRevisionId] => 
    [iconLink] => 
    [id] => 0B5CWXJTNwALMOEJkdzFvMVVsVFE
    [imageMediaMetadataType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata
    [imageMediaMetadataDataType:protected] => 
    [isAppAuthorized] => 
    [kind] => drive#file
    [lastModifyingUserType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_User
    [lastModifyingUserDataType:protected] => 
    [md5Checksum] => 
    [mimeType] => application/pdf
    [modifiedByMeTime] => 
    [modifiedTime] => 
    [name] => invoice receipt.pdf
    [originalFilename] => 
    [ownedByMe] => 
    [ownersType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_User
    [ownersDataType:protected] => array
    [parents] => 
    [permissionsType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_Permission
    [permissionsDataType:protected] => array
    [properties] => 
    [quotaBytesUsed] => 
    [shared] => 
    [sharedWithMeTime] => 
    [sharingUserType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_User
    [sharingUserDataType:protected] => 
    [size] => 
    [spaces] => 
    [starred] => 
    [thumbnailLink] => 
    [trashed] => 
    [version] => 
    [videoMediaMetadataType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata
    [videoMediaMetadataDataType:protected] => 
    [viewedByMe] => 
    [viewedByMeTime] => 
    [viewersCanCopyContent] => 
    [webContentLink] => 
    [webViewLink] => 
    [writersCanShare] => 
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Now, trying to apply the download code as below

```
$fileId = '0B5CWXJTNwALMOEJkdzFvMVVsVFE';
        $content = $drive_service->files->get($fileId,  array(
            'alt' => 'media' ));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($content->getHeaders());
        foreach ($content->getHeaders() as $name => $values) {

        header($name . ': ' . implode(', ', $values[0]));
        }
```

The file is not downloaded but was able to see the output like below

```
Array
(
    [X-GUploader-UploadID] => Array
        (
            [0] => AEnB2UrDOQ-mYxNd5tE5ctVr01jVTnh3ZykKviCBnEOjDRGtT_EIT2nbHLEM_f-2pZ22anDJpqMzbISzhcTTZY3PgsDj69PE-w
        )

    [Content-Type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/pdf
        )

    [Content-Disposition] => Array
        (
            [0] => attachment
        )

    [Vary] => Array
        (
            [0] => Origin
            [1] => X-Origin
        )

    [Expires] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tue, 23 Aug 2016 13:20:18 GMT
        )

    [Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tue, 23 Aug 2016 13:20:18 GMT
        )

    [Cache-Control] => Array
        (
            [0] => private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
        )

    [Content-Length] => Array
        (
            [0] => 80277
        )

    [X-Goog-Hash] => Array
        (
            [0] => crc32c=5yKN2g==
        )

    [Server] => Array
        (
            [0] => UploadServer
        )

    [Alternate-Protocol] => Array
        (
            [0] => 443:quic
        )

    [Alt-Svc] => Array
        (
            [0] => quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34,33,32,31,30"
        )

)
```

**Question :** How do I download the file?

**EDIT**

Based on paulo answer, have created two files as below.This is working for  image/png,  application/octet-stream,   application/pdf types, however have issues with zip/rar files (error : *This site can’t be reached*)

test.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) 
{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $results = $drive_service->files->listFiles();
    if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) 
    {
        echo "No files found";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "<br>" . count($results->getFiles()). " File(s) found" ; 
        echo "<br><table><thead><th>File Name</th><th>File Type</th><th>Download Link</th></thead><tbody>";
        foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $file->getName() . "</td><td>" . $file->getMimeType() ."</td><td><a href='gdrivedownlaod.php?fileid=". $file->getId() . "&type=" . $file->getMimeType() . "&name=" . $file->getName() . "' target='blank'>Download</a></td></tr>";// ."<br><pre>";
            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";
    }

} 
else 
{
    $redirect_uri = 'https://abcd.co/oauth2callback';
    echo "Hello, <a href='" . $redirect_uri . "'>Log in with Drive</a>";
}
```

and gdrivedownlaod.php as

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['type'])) {
//echo "We will download " . $_GET['name'] . " type " . $_GET['type'] . " with file id " . $_GET['fileid'];
    $fileId=$_GET['fileid'];
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) 
    {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $content = $drive_service->files->get($fileId,  array(
            'alt' => 'media' ));
                $fileName = $_GET['name'];
        $headers = $content->getHeaders();

        foreach ($headers as $name => $values) {
            header($name . ': ' . implode(', ', $values));
        }
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
        echo $content->getBody();
        //echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        session_destroy();
        session_unset();
        header('Location: test.php'); 
    }

}
else
echo "incorrect files ";
```

Comment: thanks paul, Have changed it. Any idea towards the solution?

Comment: Try first the suggestion in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#using_altmedia) that to download files make an authorized HTTP GET request to the file's resource URL and include the query parameter alt=media. If this method work on you, then try to double check the code that you use. Just take note that downloading the file requires the user to have at least read access. Your app must be authorized with a scope that allows reading of file content. For example, an app using the drive.readonly.metadata scope would not be authorized to download the file contents

Comment: Thanks @KENdi. I have full drive access as am able to get the metadata too. The question is how to use the guzzle response to dispatch the file in browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fileName = 'xpto.pdf';
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$content = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
    'alt' => 'media'));

$headers = $content->getHeaders();
foreach ($headers as $name => $values) {
    header($name . ': ' . implode(', ', $values));
}
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
echo $content->getBody();
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks @paulo-pinto, but its just printing the raw content instead of exporting the file

Comment: @Rajesh header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"'); for download, and header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $fileName . '"'); for view in browser. Are you open the link in a new tab?

Comment: have edited the question, please check the gdrivedownlaod.php and suggest changes

Comment: @Rajesh i test your solution and works fine to zip/tar archives, i can download with no problem. sorry i cant help.. :(

Answer (score 0):

as indicated above `$content->getHeaders()` has provided an expected output of the corresponding header information of your HTTP request.

to retrieve the file content, you will need `$content->getResponseBody()`, and then call `file_put_contents` in order to save the data into a local file.

Comment: Please can you help with the complete script part of it. I tried ```print_r($content->getResponseBody());``` nothing gets printed.

Comment: I am not good at PHP, anyway you should be able to figure that out by checking the documentation (don't be lazy. if you run into specific error after you try that, post the details here, I am sure you will get some help). By the way, your file is a PDF, and the file content is usually binary data, I don't think you can do print_r on that. Good luck.

Comment: I have already tried enough before question here. Have also tried for image type as well and the result is same. Even for the pdf, if not print was expecting it to download the file which didn't happen. The problem here is the SDK is still in beta, and their V2 api become obsolete.