# Read the csv file content

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to read the csv file content using php, google drive api v3
I got the fileid and file name but I am not sure how I can read the file content?
$service = new Drive($client);

```
    $results = $service->files->listFiles();

    $fileId="1I****************";

    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);
```

Comment: I thought that this thread might be the answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39102671

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Retrieve the CSV row data? In that case, you should convert your file to Sheets and open it with Sheets API, as suggested by others. If that's what you want to do, I'd consider posting an answer explaining this with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The google drive api is a file storage api.  It allows you to upload, download and manage storage of files.

It does not give you access to the contents of the file.

To do this you would need to download the file and open it locally.

Alternately since its a csv file you may want to consider converting it to a google sheet then you could use the google sheets api to access the data within the file programmatically.

Code for downloading a file from Google drive api would look something like this

Full sample can be found here [large-file-download.php](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/large-file-download.php)

```
 // If this is a POST, download the file
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Determine the file's size and ID
    $fileId = $files[0]->id;
    $fileSize = intval($files[0]->size);

    // Get the authorized Guzzle HTTP client
    $http = $client->authorize();

    // Open a file for writing
    $fp = fopen('Big File (downloaded)', 'w');

    // Download in 1 MB chunks
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    $chunkStart = 0;

    // Iterate over each chunk and write it to our file
    while ($chunkStart < $fileSize) {
      $chunkEnd = $chunkStart + $chunkSizeBytes;
      $response = $http->request(
        'GET',
        sprintf('/drive/v3/files/%s', $fileId),
        [
          'query' => ['alt' => 'media'],
          'headers' => [
            'Range' => sprintf('bytes=%s-%s', $chunkStart, $chunkEnd)
          ]
        ]
      );
      $chunkStart = $chunkEnd + 1;
      fwrite($fp, $response->getBody()->getContents());
    }
    // close the file pointer
    fclose($fp);
```